# How do I run a program in batch mode for big data?

Tags: linux

Quite new to handle big-data analysis.
I mainly work with DNA & RNA_seq data.

In a directory I had 10,000 files (5000 - OG*******.paml and 5000 - OG******.treefile) which start with a prefix OG****** followed by a number **(ex- OG0017769)**.

The ID's were unique.

Each id has two files -

1. OG*******.paml
2. OG*******.treefile

Using these two input files, I'd like to run a program called codeml (PAML package)[pamlgithub](https://github.com/abacus-gene/paml).

By providing all the input and output files in a configuration file (ex- codeml.ctl).

```
head -n 4 codeml.ctl 
seqfile = OG0017769.paml  * sequence data filename
treefile = OG0017769.treefile  * tree structure file name
outfile = OG0017769_out.paml * main result file name
```

Using command line -

```
codeml codeml.ctl
```

The output files -

```
# These are the output files generated from each default run # 
# default output #

2NG.dN
2NG.dS
2NG.t
4fold.nuc
lnf
rst
rst1
rub
OG0017769_out.paml
```

##### In a batch mode

```
# File 1 input #
OG0017769.paml
OG0017769.treefile

# file 1 expected output #

OG0017769.2NG.dN
OG0017769.2NG.dS
OG0017769.2NG.t
OG0017769.4fold.nuc
OG0017769.lnf
OG0017769.rst
OG0017769.rst1
OG0017769.rub
OG0017769_out.paml

# File 2 input #
OG0017771.paml
OG0017771.treefile

# file 2 expected output #

OG0017771.2NG.dN
OG0017771.2NG.dS
OG0017771.2NG.t
OG0017771.4fold.nuc
OG0017771.lnf
OG0017771.rst
OG0017771.rst1
OG0017771.rub
OG0017771_out.paml
```

Some suggestions please, how do I automate the process, by replacing the *.paml, *.treefile and *out.paml in the codeml.ctl configuration file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Define a function or write a script that takes only one argument, e.g the *.paml* file or the disctinctive number in its name, and wraps the call to `codeml` by constructing a *.ctl* file according to the argument, without changing the template *codeml.ctl* file:

```
function mycodeml(){
  num="${1//[^0-9]/}" # keep only numbers
  if [ !-f OG$num.paml ] ;then
    echo ERR NOTFOUND $PWD/OG$num.paml >&2
  else
    tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/codeml_XXX.ctl)
    sed "s/OG[0-9]*\(.paml\|.treefile\|_out.paml\)/OG$num\1/g" codeml.ctl >$tmp &&
    codeml $tmp
    rm $tmp
  fi
}
```

Then you can just run `mycodeml OGxxx.paml`

To batch it on many entries at a time, collect them with `ls` and `grep` and inject to `xargs`:

```
ls | grep 'OG[0-9]*.paml' | xargs -l1 mycodeml
```

or parallelized:

```
ls | grep 'OG[0-9]*.paml' | parallel mycodeml
```